# Conversion of one line shell script in yaml?

Tags: shell, yaml

I have very simple question to ask: I have an endless loop shell written in /bin/bash, something like this:

```
while true; do hackbench; done
```

How should I write exact the same line in .yaml?

Something like this:

```
command: "while true; do hackbench; done"
```

Or similar?

Answer (score 2):

YAML is not a programming language, so you can't write a (working) script in it like you can with `bash`. What you could do is write a program which will interpret the YAML file, but that is seriously out of scope for this question.